# HTML5 transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Looking for some examples of HTML5 transition I adapted what I found to finally get what I exactly want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
        }

        div.myDiv {
          position: absolute;
          -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
          -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
          -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

          -moz-transition-property: top, opacity;
          -moz-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
          -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

          -o-transition-property: top, opacity;
          -o-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
          -o-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

          transition-property: top, opacity;
          transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
          transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
        }
        #one {
          top: 0px;
          background-color: blue;
          opacity: 1;
        }

        #two {
          top: 50px;
          background-color: green;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        #three {
          top: 100px;
          background-color: red;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        #container {
          width: 50px;
          height: 150px;
          position: relative;
          overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    function one() {
      document.getElementById('one').style.top = "0px";
      document.getElementById('two').style.top = "50px";
      document.getElementById('three').style.top = "100px";

      document.getElementById('one').style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById('two').style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById('three').style.opacity = "0";
    }
    function two() {
      document.getElementById('one').style.top = "-50px";
      document.getElementById('two').style.top = "0px";
      document.getElementById('three').style.top = "50px";

      document.getElementById('one').style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById('two').style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById('three').style.opacity = "0";
    }

    function three() {
      document.getElementById('one').style.top = "-100px";
      document.getElementById('two').style.top = "-50px";
      document.getElementById('three').style.top = "0px";

      document.getElementById('one').style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById('two').style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById('three').style.opacity = "1";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div class="myDiv" id='one'>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id='two'>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id='three'>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' onclick='one();' value='one!'></input>
<input type='button' onclick='two();' value='two!'></input>
<input type='button' onclick='three();' value='three!'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I read somewhere that is not recommendable to change css properties from a javascript. I think its a bad practice. I'm sure there must be a more elegant and better way to do this.

Any idea? (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EgSJ5/))

Comment: Transitions are CSS, not HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about it necessarily being bad practice to change CSS properties in JavaScript, though perhaps if there's a possibility that your user's will have JavaScript turned off you may not want to change properties which are fundamental to the functioning of the site that way.

Your JavaScript could be refactored as follows, with the obvious advantage that it makes it trivial to add or remove boxes (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9ATF/)):

```
  // We can define any number of boxes here
  var boxes = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];
  var height = 50;

  // We'll put the boxes in a div which we will move 
  // so that we don't have to manage the movement of 
  // multiple elements
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var div;

  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i ++) {

    // Create a box for each element in array
    div = document.createElement('div');

    div.setAttribute('id', 'box_' + i);
    div.setAttribute('class', 'myDiv');

    div.style.background = boxes[i];
    div.style.top = (i * height) + "px";
    div.style.opacity = (i == 0) ? 1 : 0;

    // Now stick it in the slider div
    slider.appendChild(div);
  }

  function slide(index) {

    // Calculate new slider position according to supplied index
    var top = (index * height) * -1;

    document.getElementById('slider').style.top = top + 'px';
    toggleVisible(document.getElementById('box_' + index));
  }

  // Hide non-selected boxes and reveal selected
  function toggleVisible(show) { 

    var div;

    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i ++) {
      div = document.getElementById('box_' + i);
      div.style.opacity = (div === show) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='slider'></div>
</div>

<input type='button' onclick='slide(0);' value='one!'></input>
<input type='button' onclick='slide(1);' value='two!'></input>
<input type='button' onclick='slide(2);' value='three!'></input>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div.myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -o-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
}

#container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#slider { 
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition-property: top;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  -moz-transition-property: top;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  -o-transition-property: top;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -o-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

  transition-property: top;
  transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-timing-function:ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: The point is that div must contain content(text, images...). I just put boxes for the example. Anyway, I thing I can modify it so it fits to my needs. Thanks!